# Wilson Coefficients in the Standard Model

Tags: particle-physics, statistics, effective-field-theory, mesons, leptons

I'm not particularly knowledgeable in this area of physics. From my understanding as an undergraduate, Wilson coefficients are sets of parameters that arise from an effective field theory  which describe the interaction strength between high energy and low energy particles?

They are particularly useful for looking at hints of new physics, as their value changes as a result of new physics contributions.

I'm working on a project where we are given some data from a $B_{0} \rightarrow K^{*}\mu^{+}
\mu{-}$ decay, and have to apply some preselection and ML to isolate reduce the background as much as possible, then adjust for detector effects and the preselection itself by using an acceptance function. Doing this, we can find values for angular observables, e.g. $F_{L}$, $A_{fb}$, $S_{3}$.

We then use a python package called Flavio, which allows us to make theoretical standard model predictions of these observables, for comparison. It also allows us to determine Wilson coefficients ($C_9$ and maybe $C_10$ are most important for us because I think they are most sensitive to new physics contributions) that best match our data, using a FastLikelihood method (essentially it determines a likelihood function related to the underlying relation between the observables and Wilson coefficients, and this likelihood function is related to the chi-square, and it varies Wilson coefficients until it finds a best fit). We apply this to different 5 different bins of dilepton mass squared, $q^2$ between $0.1\:\text{GeV}^{2}<q^2 <6\:\text{GeV}^{2}$. From my understanding why use an upper limit of $q^2 =6\:\text{GeV}^{2}$ because Flavio predictions are unreliable as the light resonances resulting from virtual particles with masses lower than the $B_0$ meson are significant at higher $q^2$ and are too computationally intensive and complex for us to model.

We are aiming to calculate pull parameters for each $q^2$ bin, which I believe quantifies the difference between our Wilson coefficients and the SM prediction (and then as normal, $>3\sigma$ could hint at new physics effects).

However, I'm a bit confused about Wilson coefficients in the standard model. Does $C_9$ have a specific defined value at a defined energy scale (e.g. $4.8\:\text{GeV}$)? I'm unable to understand the literature regarding this?